# Get a list of remote VPCs on AWS using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-vpc

I'd like to get a list of all remote VPCs from AWS with terraform. I've read the documentation and found two data sources:

1. **AWS_DEFAULT_VPC**
2. **AWS_VPC**

The first one will give you the default VPC and the second one accepts a VPC id and toss out other information such as subnets...

How can I get a list of all VPCs existing in ceratin AWS region (US-West-2 for instance) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use the output of the list in a for loop to get the subnet ids for_each, but it would look something like this:

```
data "aws_vpcs" "foo" {}

output "vpcs" {
  value = data.aws_vpcs.foo.ids
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Terraform data sources.

Terraform official link :
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/vpc

###### Example:

```
variable "vpc_id" {}

data "aws_vpc" "selected" {
  id = var.vpc_id
}

resource "aws_subnet" "example" {
  vpc_id            = data.aws_vpc.selected.id
  availability_zone = "us-west-2a"
  cidr_block        = cidrsubnet(data.aws_vpc.selected.cidr_block, 4, 1)
}
```